# Приведение дат к общему виду в запросе

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица с полем типа "дата":

```
+---------------------+
| DATE_IN             |
+---------------------+
| 17.02.2014 18:56:14 |
| 22.12.2015          |
| (null)              |
| 14.06.2015 17:48:12 |
+---------------------+
```

Как в запросе привести значения к виду `DD.MM.YYYY HH.mm.SS`, чтобы там, где часов, минут и секунд нет, стало `00:00:00`.

Comment: в mysql можно так: `update thetable set DATE_IN=date(DATE_IN)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типа данных "дата" не бывает. Или `date` или `char`. Так как в вопросе вывод поля `date_in` имеет различный формат, со временем и без него, то тип данных этого поля символьный.

Функция `to_char()` приведёт сначала к неявному преобразованию в тип `date`, что совершенно излишне и может вызвать ошибку. Правильный ответ будет:

```
 to_date (date_in, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Воспроизводимый пример:

```sql
select to_date (date_in, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') date_in
from (
    select trim (column_value) date_in from XmlTable (
    '"17.02.2014 18:56:14",
     "22.12.2015         "'));

DATE_IN            
-------------------
2014-02-17 18:56:14
2015-12-22 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to_char(date_in, 'DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```